# Solve for $x$ in Infinite Power Sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 5x^{3n} = 38$$

I've gotten to the point of saying

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x^n)^3 = \frac{38}{5}$$

I know that I can use $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ ($|x|<1$) from here but not sure what to do with the $(x^n)^3$.

Comment: If you want to use a formula that says $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \text{something},$ for ALL values of $x$ in some interval, then you need to write your sum in the form $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\text{something})^n \qquad.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $t = x^3$
We have 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t^n = \frac{38}{5}$$
$$\frac{1}{1-t} - 1= \frac{38}{5}$$
$$1-t=\frac{5}{43}$$
$$t= \frac{38}{43}$$
$$x= \Big(\frac{38}{43}\Big)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Answer (score 4):

You have to realize that $(x^n)^3$ is nothing but $(x^3)^n.$

Use $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}(x^3)^n =\frac{x^3}{1-x^3}$ to solve further.

Comment: I'm being told this answer is incorrect. Not sure if it is to do with the formula or the fact that the sequence starts at $n=1$? (The answer being $\frac{33}{38}^{1/3}$

Comment: @djde You are right SARTHAK GUPTA has done a mistake

Comment: Recall that $\sum _{\color{red}{n=0}}^\infty r^n=\frac{1}{1-r}$. But we don't have $n=0$ here, so ...

Comment: @Jam in this case do I just subtract 1 from that general formula?

Comment: @djde Yes. Alternatively, the way I was taught the formula in school was $\sum r^n=\frac{a}{1-r}$, where $a$ is the first term and $r$ is the ratio. So you wouldn't have to worry about getting the index wrong in that case.

Comment: @djde Thanks for pointing out. I will correct it